# How to insert text or HTML to a specific DOM element by python+selenium+WebDriver?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Could anybody advise, how to insert text or HTML to a specific DOM element by Python + selenium + WebDriver?

Answer (score 9):

You can set the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) value of an element through [`execute_script()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script):

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_id("my_id")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'My Text';", elm)
```

Comment: @user2987260 good, see if the answer can be accepted. Thanks.